# jquery autocompleter for array input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [autocompleter js plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-autocompleter) that works fine for first input field. But not able to work for next input field which i have added using 'Add More' button, even reinitializing autocomplete function after cloning the input field.

HTML Part:

```
<div id='multiUser'>
 <input type='input' name='search_user[]' class='searchClas'/>
</div>
<span id='add_more' class='btn'>Add More</span>
```

Javascript Part:

```
<script>
$("body").on("click","#add_more",function(){
    var cloneHTML="<input type='input' name='search_user[]' class='searchClas'/>";
    $("#multiUser").append(cloneHTML);

   $('.searchClas').autocompleter({

    cache: false,
    source:url,
    combine: function(params) {
      var add_info = $('input[name=add_info]').val();

      return {
        q: params.query,
        count: params.limit,
        add_info: add_info
      };
    },
    callback: function(value, index, object) {
      console.log(
        'Value ' + value + ' are selected (with index ' + index + ').'
      );
      console.log(object);
    }
  });

});

$(function() {
  $('.searchClas').autocompleter({

    cache: false,
    source:url,
    combine: function(params) {
      var add_info = $('input[name=add_info]').val();

      return {
        q: params.query,
        count: params.limit,
        add_info: add_info
      };
    },
    callback: function(value, index, object) {
      console.log(
        'Value ' + value + ' are selected (with index ' + index + ').'
      );
      console.log(object);
    }
  });
});


</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what you asking...I don't understand what is single input field and what is input array. Also please try add a working snippet.

Comment: single input, meant single field i.e <input type='input' name='search' class='searchClas'/>, while multiple input meant multiple input with same name which we denote using e.g. name='search[]'

Comment: First, I would like to see how have coded for using multiple inputs with an array. could you please add few more details for the code changes?

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar, please checkout sample my code

Comment: Thank you, Are the input fields are adding correctly when you click `Add More` button?

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar. Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. By cloning field, it was also cloning the class of autocompleter plugin which was causing the issue and preventing the autocompleter plugin to reinitialize it.